# Django: Problem with Using Slug in Templates

Tags: python, django, slug

I am a beginner in Django. I am building a Django app, named PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models.

I have already created models, views and the template files. Now, I am facing a problem. I can't use slug in URLs. Right now, it looks like this:
[image]

Here are my codes of **models.py** located inside **PhoneReview** folder:

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.brand_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.model_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    link = models.TextField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are my codes of **urls.py** located inside **PhoneReview** folder:

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<int:pk>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are my codes of **views.py** located inside **PhoneReview** folder:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PhoneModel
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are my codes of **apps.py** located inside **PhoneReview** folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are my codes of **index.html** located inside **templates** folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
<!--            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>-->
            <li><a href = "{% url 'modellist' brand.id %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>

        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are my codes of **phonemodel.html** located inside **templates** folder:

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

In **index.html**, I tried to replace `<li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>` with `<li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>`. But I get error.

How can I fix the issue?

**Update:** I added the codes provided by @arjun. However, I am getting an error. It says the following

```
OperationalError at /index
no such table: PhoneReview_brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `slug` instead of `pk` through your url if you want to use slug

```
path('phonemodel/<slug:slug>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
path('details/<slug:slug>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
```

Now in template instead of id

```
<li><a href = "{% url 'details' phonemodel.slug %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>
```

And it's better to have unique slug field

```
 slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, unique=True)
```

Also I will suggest you to use the [django-autoslug](https://github.com/justinmayer/django-autoslug). It is a reusable Django library that provides an improved slug field which can automatically populate itself from another field.

EDIT:You haven't passed  `context_object_name`  in your detail view so provide the context here

```
class ModelView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PhoneModel
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'
    context_object_name= 'phonemodel'
```

Comment: When I add your codes, I get "Page not found (404)" error. It says the following: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/phonemodel/1/
Raised by: PhoneReview.views.ModelView
No phone model found matching the query

Comment: @Shawn if you are using `slug` then instead of id `1` provide your slug field.`127.0.0.1:8000/phonemodel/you-slug-field`

Comment: The links are supposed to be generated automatically when click on phone model, like Galaxy S10.

Comment: I am not supposed to type any URL in the browser. Upon clicking phone mode, like Galaxy S10, the link is supposed to be generated automatically.

Comment: @Shawn yes it will generate

Comment: @Shawn what changes did you make ?

Comment: When the link is generated automatically, I get the 404 error.

Comment: I just added your code. That's the change that I had made.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202184/discussion-between-arjun-and-shawn).

Comment: I have added your codes. But I am getting an error. Please, see my message on chat.

Comment: Would please tell me the meaning of `<slug:slug>`? I mean, why are we using slug:slug here?

Comment: @Shawn because it's a slug.Just like we are specifying int for pk with `<int:pk>`

Comment: Yes, I had figured it out a few hours ago. Thanks for answering.